# Tapestry DateField extend range of dates

Tags: java, html, datepicker, tapestry

I'm testing out Tapestry am trying out the DateField component. It is working, but the range of dates is just for the current month. Is there a way to extend the choice so that I can set older dates, like previous months?

Thanks.

Comment: Please put some more details. Just adding t:type="datefield" should work fine.

Comment: I'm using the DateField component like so:
<t:DateField t:id="acceptanceDate"    t:value="currentDoc.acceptanceDate" t:validate="required" disabled="${editable}" style="width:80px;" />.
Now, the field works just fine, except it only gives days from the current month, with no option to change month or year.